# Unclear OR NOT syntax

Tags: c

Very basic question (I am a total noob in C...)

I have a piece of code written:

```
if(!_a[_item[i]] || _b[_item[i]])
```

Does this mean the next line should be run if:

- item[i] is **not present in a or in b**

or does it mean it should be run if:

- item[i] is **not present in a** or  **is present in b**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although an answer has been selected for this question, I'm going to chime in anyway.

The code

```
if(!_a[_item[i]] || _b[_item[i]])
```

Does **not** determine the (non) presence of `_item[i]` in `_a` or `_b`.  What it does is say:

> The numerical value of the element `_item[i]` of array `_a` is zero or the numerical value of
>   the element `_item[i]` of array `_b` is non-zero

Whether that maps to the concept of `presence` is an architectural decision that is irrelevant to how the `if` statement is processed.

Comment: Thanks - this is relevant as it is actually sorting through four binary options (so it is effectively saying "if the binary is not 10")

Comment: @Joni The thing to remember is that C has no bool type, and it effectively overloads true/false onto not-zero/zero values.

Answer (score 2):

It means `item[i]` is not present in `a` or is present in `b`

Comment: Thanks - thought this made no sense in the context, but now understand it

Comment: Hey @fudu, welcome to StackOverflow.  Just a heads up: to make text appear as code, surround them with backticks `\`like this\``, not dollar signs.

Answer (score 2):

So, we can always look at the [operator precedence tables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), but I usually have some trouble following that. So let's write some code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", (!true || true)); // Outputs 1 (true)
}
```

So, let's see which of the two variants makes sense:

- If we have `((!true) || true)` then this makes sense.
- If we have `(!(true || true))` then this **does not** make sense.

So, we can pretty clearly say that these two expressions are the same:

```
(!_a[_item[i]] || _b[_item[i]])
((!_a[_item[i]]) || _b[_item[i]])
```

And thus, we know that the next line will run if `_item[i]` is not present in `a` or it is present in `b`.

Answer (score 0):

`!` has higher precedence than `||`. The first term is negated, the second one isn't. It's equivalent to `( (!(_a[_item[i]])) || _b[_item[i]] )`

Answer (score 0):

Check the operator precedence (e.g. on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)), you'll find that `!` is evaluated before the `||` and thus the expression is parsed like this:

```
if((!_a[_item[i]]) || _b[_item[i]])
```

btw. if you see (!A || B) this is known as `implies` in logic: `A implies B == !A || B`